# What is the Equivalent of C#'s "List <String>" in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm working with an API and it is asking me to provide a `List <String>` value. I'm writing PHP and can only seem to find this type in C#.

Is it an array? A comma-separated string?

Comment: Is this a web service, or are you calling the method directly?

Comment: I'm calling the method via SOAP through a web service.

Comment: I know this question is really old, but it saved me a huge headache. So, thank you for asking this 7 years ago @DaveKiss

Comment: @DonCarlosII boooom! I remember those days…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP does not have the concept of generic types.

You can use [array()](http://php.net/array):

**PHP**

```
 $arr = array();  
 $arr[0] = 'foo';
```

equivalent in **C#**

```
List<string> arr = new List<string>(); 
arr.Add("foo");
```

Answer (score 8):

I guess that you can use a simple array:

```
$list = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3');
```

or

```
$list = array();
$list[] = 'string1';
$list[] = 'string2';
$list[] = 'string3';
```

etc.

Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php for details.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it an array?

Yes, it is

> A comma-separated string?

No, it isn't

Answer (score 1):

PHP is untyped, so you can use your array for all type of variable,use this code:

```
$arr=array();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling SOAP then you should just use php's SoapClient class, it does a good job at converting types it sees in wsdl into native php structures, usually into arrays or often into instances of stdClass objects, which is php's type of class that can store any value as property. Also you can do a more interesting things like tell php's SoapClient to map return types to your own php's objects.

See https://www.php.net/SoapClient
and also see definition of constructor https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php and one of the options called 'classmap' explains how you can map returned types to your own classes. There is also a 'typemap' option to map return types to your own types

Answer (score 1):

This thread is old, but I think that code may helps:

```php
class ClientList implements IteratorAggregate {

   protected $data;

   public function __construct(Client ...$data){
      $this->data = $data;
   }

   public function getIterator(): Traversable {
      return new ArrayIterator($this->data);
   }

}

class Client {

}


$clients[] = new Client();
$clients[] = new Client();

$clientList = new ClientList(...$clients);

foreach($clientList as $client){
   var_dump($client);
}
```

Now when you insert a string, number or something that isn't a Client instance that you would get error, and thanks to `IteratorAggregate` you can iterate on ClientList object.