# C# List equivalent in PHP for SOAP call

Tags: c#, php

Have some trouble making the equivalent in PHP of this C# code (to be used in a SOAP call).

C#

```
var articleQueries = new List<ArticleQuery>;
articleQueries.Add(new ArticleQuery { ArticleNumber = 1 });
articleQueries.Add(new ArticleQuery { ArticleNumber = 2 });
```

Have read [What is the Equivalent of C#'s “List ” in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449664/what-is-the-equivalent-of-cs-list-string-in-php) with no success.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't have lists, but it does have arrays.

You can use arrays as stacks by using `array_push`. Then you can take items out again by using `array_pop`, just as if the array were a stack.

Check out W3CSchool's PHP Array reference at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp.

Comment: Thanks. Then my problem seems to be the call to ArticleQuery Class (C#) from the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a general field that can be used as a List and Dictionary. Equivalent for add is `[]`. More about PHP array: http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php

```
$articleQueries = array();

$obj = new ArticleQuery();
$obj->ArticleNumber = 1;
$articleQueries[] = $obj;

$obj = new ArticleQuery();
$obj->ArticleNumber = 2;
$articleQueries[] = $obj;
```